# App signing certificate and upload certificate have same fingerprints

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, code-signing

We have a weird issue in Google play where the `App signing certificate` and `upload certificate` have the same `MD5, SH1, SH256`.  Our other apps dont, and this app is having trouble being signed.  Was there a misconfiguration of some sort with this app at some point and if so how can we fix it?

[image]

Comment: commonly it occurred when an app's `certificates` are also configured in another google account

Comment: Sorry I dont know what that means

Comment: means these certificates are already configured in another (different user's) account or another google project against same user...

Comment: And both certs have the same signature? That doesn’t make sense.  Our other apps have the same app signing very, but the upload very is different not the same as the app signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I suspect happened. Usually Google Play App Signing creates the signing key for you. However, in the case of a pre-existing app, obviously the signing key can't change. So you surrender your existing private key to Google. This is the [Opt in an existing app section in the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

I suspect when whoever opted in to app signing did it, in step 3 they didn't create a new upload key. It's recommended but not compulsory.

I'd recommend following the steps at the bottom of that page under "Reset a lost or compromised private upload key" to contact Google Play support and change your upload key.

Comment: They reset the key to the one we usually use and all is well now.